# Closure open ball

Tags: general-topology

Can somebody tell me why $\overline B(0,1)$={0} if we consider the trival metric (so d(x,y)=0 if x=y and d(x,y)=1 if x is not equal to y. With the overline I mean the closure. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The closure of $B(0,1)$ is intersection of all closed sets containing it. Since you have the discrete topology, $\{y\}$ is open for all $y\neq 0$, and so $X \setminus \{y\}$ is a closed set which contains $B(0,1)$, but not $y$. Thus,  $\forall y \neq 0$, $y\notin \bar{B}(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$B(0,1)=\{x\in X:d(x,0)<1\}=\{0\},$$ 
because $d(x,y)=1$ whenever $y\neq x$. And take the closure.